# Grails Spring Security REST Plugin - Token Storage Failure

Tags: rest, grails, spring-security

I'm setting up a Grails project with the Spring Security REST Plugin and I'm having some trouble.  When I make the following request to `/api/login` with valid username and password

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "validuser",
    "password": "validpassword"
}
```

I get the following exceptions

```
Error 2014-08-09 11:30:04,839 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR [/myphotoid-api].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/myphotoid-api] threw exception
Message: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Line | Method
->>   38 | storeToken in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.GormTokenStorageService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     97 | doFilter   in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|     82 | doFilter . in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|     63 | doFilter   in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter
|     82 | doFilter . in com.brandseye.cors.CorsFilter
|   1145 | runWorker  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run        in java.lang.Thread
```

and then my client receives a 302 to `/login/auth`, the regular stateful login page. :(

However if I make the following request to `/api/login` with an invalid username and password

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "username": "validuser",
    "password": "badpassword"
}
```

I get a 401, which I guess is what I should expect.

Here is the valid section from my `Config.groovy`

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.PersonRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/api/login':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.AuthenticationToken
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                          // Traditional chain
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like your `tokenDomainClassName` needs to be enclosed within quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kau Thanks for the helpful comment.

> Looks like your tokenDomainClassName needs to be enclosed within quotes –  kau Aug 22 at 14:01

so I changed this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.AuthenticationToken
```

to this

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'com.campuscardtools.myphotoid.AuthenticationToken'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check plugin confiugraiton section in documentation : http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/configuration.html

You have to configure chains properly in grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',  // Stateless chain
'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'                                          // Traditional chain
```

]